# Viewing SQL Server data to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, gateway

Hello I have created a Database Link from Oracle to SQL Server 2008 using Oracle Gateway.

DB LINK:

```
create public database link mssql
connect to "user" identified by "password" 
using 'gateway-SID';
```

When I use a simple query as `SELECT * FROM TABLE@MSSQL` the results are clearly ok.

The problem occurs when I select a distinct column from a table e.g.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE@mssql
```

I get a query error from my SQL Developer saying:

> ORA-00904: "CUSTOMERID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   Cause:
>   Action:
>   Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm no SQL Server expert, but I'll give it a go)

SQL Server is case sensitive - you have to quote your column names, so instead of

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE@mssql
```

you need

```
SELECT "COLUMN_NAME" FROM TABLE@mssql
```

or even

```
SELECT "COLUMN_NAME" FROM "TABLE"@mssql
```

See [Oracle forums on SQL Server, Oracle Gateway and ORA-00904](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2297633)

Comment: actually you don't "have" to quote the object names - it is just that in some cases they may be case-sensitive (in SQL Server), and thus it is not clear what is the referred object - thankfully you can use quotes to make names clearer, like in OS shells ...